# Sort with re.search() - Python

Tags: python, regex

i have some problems with solving the follwoing problem.

I have to *.txt files in both files are cities from austria. In the first file "cities1" are the cities are ordered by population.

The first file (cities1.txt) is looking like this:

```
1.,Vienna,Vienna,1.840.573
2.,Graz,Styria,273.838
3.,Linz,Upper Austria,198.181
4.,Salzburg,Salzburg,148.420
5.,Innsbruck,Tyrol,126.851
```

The second file (cities2.txt) is looking like this:

```
"Villach","Carinthia",60480,134.98,501
"Innsbruck","Tyrol",126851,104.91,574
"Graz","Styria",273838,127.57,353
"Dornbirn","Vorarlberg",47420,120.93,437
"Vienna","Vienna",1840573,414.78,151
"Linz","Upper Austria",198181,95.99,266
"Klagenfurt am Woerthersee","Carinthia",97827,120.12,446
"Salzburg","Salzburg",148420,65.65,424
"Wels","Upper Austria",59853,45.92,317
"Sankt Poelten","Lower Austria",52716,108.44,267
```

What i like to do, or in other words what i should do is, the first file `cities1.txt` is already sorted. I only need the second element of every line. That means i only need the name of the city. For example from the line `2.,Graz,Styria,273.838`, i only need Graz.

Than second i should print out the area of the city, this is the fourth element of every line in `cities2.txt`. That means, for example from the third line `"Graz","Styria",273838,127.57,353`, i only need `127.57`.

At the end the console should display the following:

```
Vienna,414.78
Graz,127.57
Linz,95.99
Salzburg,65.65
Innsbruck,104.91
```

So, my problem now is, how can i do this, if i only allowed to use the `re.search()` method. Cause the second *.txt file is not in the same order and i have to bring the cities in the same order as in the first file that this will work, or?

I know, it would be much easier to use `re.split()` because than you are able to compare the list elements form both files. But I'm not allowed to do this.

I hope someone can help me and sorry for the long text.

Comment: You don't need RE for this - just string split on comma. Read the second file first and build a dictionary keyed by the city name and with a value which is the penultimate token resulting from the split. Then, work through the first file isolating the second token (the city name) and get the value from the dictionary that you built from the second file.

Comment: I know that i can do this withou RE, but the problem is, this is an university example, and i am only allowed to use RE at this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation based on my earlier comment:

```
with open('cities2.txt') as c:
    D = {}
    for line in c:
        t = line.split(',')
        cn = t[0].strip('"')
        D[cn] = t[-2]
    with open('cities1.txt') as d:
        for line in d:
            t = line.split(',')
            print(f'{t[1]},{D[t[1]]}')
```

Note that this may not be robust. If there's a city name in cities1.txt that does not exist in cities2.txt then you'll get a KeyError

Comment: This is a good idea with split, but i am only allowed to use re.search()

Comment: I'm no expert on RE but my understanding is that re.search() returns either None or a match object for the first (and only) pattern matching the given expression. If I'm right then using re.search on its own for this may be a challenge

Comment: If i would allowed to do, i would also do it like you with the split method. But maybe there is an RE Expert

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hint, it's your university assignment after all.

```
import re

TEST = '2.,Graz,Styria,273.838'

RE = re.compile('^[^,]*,([^,]*),')

if match := RE.search(TEST):
    print(match.group(1)) # 'Graz'
```

Let's break down the regexp:

```
 ^      - start of line
 [^,]*  - any character except a comma - repeated 0 or more times
          this is the first field
 ,      - one comma character
          this is the field separator
 (      - start capturing, we are interested in this field
 [^,]*  - any character except a comma - repeated 0 or more times
          this is the second field
 )      - stop capturing
 ,      - one comma character
 (don't care about the rest of line)
```

Comment: That helped me a lot! Thanks!
Thanks also for the detailed explanation!